# Test a model with random data on GLPK

Tags: random, glpk

I'm new on GLPK, I want to test my simple model,
I use this comment to generate different random data:

```
param seed:=gmtime();
param u{(i,j) in E}:=(round(seed*Uniform01())) mod 40 ;
```

and I want to solve model for 100 times and obtain the average value of optimal value of objective function.

I don't know how to code iterated expression to repeat solving model  in .mod file. Could you please help me?

This is my model:

```
###  VARIABLES  ###
var x{(i,j) in E} >= 0, <= u[i,j];
###  OBJECTIVE  ###
maximize Val: sum {(1,j) in E} x[1,j];
###  CONSTRAINTS  ###
subject to Balance {i in V diff {1,n}}:
  sum {(j,i) in E} x[j,i] = sum {(i,k) in E} x[i,k];
solve;
```

Comment: Is it possible to you to provide a more complete model (working example)? I don't know exactly how to complete the missing rows.

Answer (score 1):

I also asked this question in  "https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-glpk",
and I got this answer from   Heinrich Schuchardt and  it works.
"Dear Shaghayegh,

glpsol cannot iterate over multiple models or data sets by itself.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Scripting_plus_MathProg
shows how to use a scripting language to call glpsol multiple times.

You can pass the seed value for the random number generator like this

glpsol --seed SEEDVALUE

In awk you can use function rand() to create random numbers."

To complete the model, the only thing we need is to add following comments:

```
param n >=1  integer; # Number of nodes
set V := 1..n;  # Set of nodes
set E within (V cross V);  # Set of arcs
```

This is a maximum flow problem.